# Linux: Browsing Windows file shares with a tree view

Tags: linux, networking, smb

In the Thunar file manager, tree view does not expand for 'Network' section even once I click device name,

[image]

It is possible to browse **.gvfs**, but it has problems with file deletion ('can not find trash directory') and sometimes with updating the list once the file was deleted.

In Thunar, adding `smb://name_here/` to bookmarks disappears after restart.

Which file manager can handle windows share browsing in a nice way?

- navigable tree view (top priority)
- saved bookmarks (probably built-in, but not necessary, as "gigolo" does this as separate app)

---

This is how Windows does it

[image]

Each network device ('Laptop', 'Desktop' in this case) is fully navigable using the tree view. This is how it worked since Windows 98 or so.

### Purpose

- How to enable this function in Thunar?
- Which other file managers support the function described? Please: do **NOT** add new answer if it's mentioned already, please expand an original answer instead. I expect a list of different file managers which do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunar is not a network file-manager, and this is done on purpose.

There is a workaround, as written in the 
the [Thunar FAQ](http://thunar.xfce.org/pwiki/documentation/faq#when_will_it_support_sambanetwork_browsing) :

> **When will it support samba/network browsing?**
>
> Thunar is designed to be a file manager, not a network file system
>   manager. [...]
>
> Short answer: not any time soon unless you write it yourself.
>
> For Linux users, and especially Xubuntu users, the following thread
>   can help: [Xubuntu How to: Thunar Native Windows Network Browsing](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=304131&highlight=xfce%20samba).
>   You will need fusesmb. For me it worked like a charm with Feisty.

If you prefer to use another file manager for better network browsing, nautilus for example, these articles may help :

[nautilus set as default filemanager howto](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=269669&highlight=nautilus)
[DefaultFileManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager)
[10 File Managers for Linux](http://tuxarena.blogspot.com/2009/04/10-file-managers-for-linux.html)

Comment: I already can browse `~/.gvfs` which is the mount point. What advantage does fusesmb give?

Comment: I never tried fusesmb or used Xubuntu. I only quoted this because it *might* be useful. The important part is that Thunar as-is does not support Samba. Unless somebody else comes up with a better idea, I think you should simply choose some other less-minimal file-manager that better fits your needs.

Comment: I am looking for an example of a file manager which works like what I need, rather than a link to "10 Linux file managers".  If you don't know, second part of your advice has no merit - I already tried few and have no intention to go on randomly.

Comment: The answer to your first question about Thunar is : Impossible. For the second, the answer is a matter of personal taste. For me nautilus is fine, but maybe not for you.

Comment: Acknowledged. "thunar impossible" and "nautilus does this". +1.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Commander do what you want... (Samba supported)

http://www.nongnu.org/gcmd/download.html

[image]

:-)

Comment: Sorry, I need GUI.

Comment: ? There is a GUI (not fancy...) :)

Comment: Uh...? I mean treeview gui, sorry. It's pretty interesting, +1, though.